# In Velocity, how can I make the template render nulls, null pointers and index out of bound exceptions as blank?

Tags: java, null, velocity, mustache

I've got a velocity template that has a line in it like this:

```
$person.names.get(0).FullName
```

The problem is that if `names` is null, or `get(0)` returns null, this gets evaluated to the literal of

```
$person.names.get(0).FullName
```

Instead, I want this to print "" without the quotes.  Is there a way to configure Velocity to work this way?  I don't want to have to wrap every thing I do with an

```
#if (x != null && x.somethingElse != null ...) 
    ... 
#end
```

I've been looking at [mustache](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java) and it seems to work this way by default.

Answer (score 3):

```
    VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
    EventCartridge eventCartridge = new EventCartridge();
    eventCartridge.addReferenceInsertionEventHandler(new ReferenceInsertionEventHandler() {
        public Object referenceInsert(String reference, Object value) {
            if (value == null) {
                return StringUtils.EMPTY;
            } else {
                return value;
            }
        }
    });
    context.attachEventCartridge(eventCartridge);
```

There will still be errors on index out of bounds.  I have a feeling there's no way to avoid that.  If someone can figure out a way, I'll gladly mark that as an answer.